# How to get all connections of a Linkedin user

Tags: php, api, linked-list, linkedin-api

I am trying to develop a program in PHP to import all the connections of a linked in user. I am trying the below API code

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location:(name),picture-url,emailAddress);
```

But it only display the connections of the current user,I need to get the connections of other users.for example i need to import the connection of LinkedIn user with name 'Firstname Lastname'.

How it possible to get the connections of other Linkedin users ?

Please give a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Who is the "current user"? Can't you change `first-name, last-name` to `ABC GHJ`?

Comment: current user means the login user or the user which create the API_KEY and API_SECRET.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible through the API, only the current logged in user's 1st degree connections are available.